# Leer QR desde fragment y retornar el resultado al fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, qrcode

Buenas, tengo el siguiente código que me funciona cuando trabajo con actividades normales, el caso es que ahora estoy haciendo una app dependiente de fragments, por lo que no se de que manera hacer esta solicitud:

Código para leer el qr

```
scanbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PreScan.this, LeerQR.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
```

Esta actividad recibe los valores que resultan de la actividad `LeerQR.class`

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        if(data != null){
            final Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra("barcode");
            result.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    result.setText(barcode.displayValue);
```

Ahora bien, desde leerQR me envía la respuesta a mi actividad de vuelta:

```
     @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes =  detections.getDetectedItems();
            if(barcodes.size() > 0){
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                //String [] variables = barcodes.split(=);
                intent.putExtra("barcode", barcodes.valueAt(0));
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
```

La pregunta es, cómo puedo hacer todo esto con fragment, como puedo llamar a la siguiente actividad (que es un fragment) y que el resultado me lo devuelva de tal manera que lo pueda usar como ya esta programado en la actividad.

Edito, este es mi preScan fragment:

```
    public class PreScan extends Fragment {
Button btnscan;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
TextView result;
String montooper, comCorreo;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 100;
public static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 200;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pre_scan, container, false);
    btnscan = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_scanear);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
    }
    btnscan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //Esto es lo que debo pasar al siguiente fragment, y recibir la respuesta para poder procesarla
           // Intent intent = new Intent(PreScan.this, LeerQR.class);
           // startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        if(data != null){
            final Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra("barcode");
            result.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    result.setText(barcode.displayValue);
                    //aqui proceso el resultado. en una actividad funciona sin problema, aqui no, ya que no se como hacer con los fragments    

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

}

Este es donde deberia procesarse:

```
    public class LeerQR extends AppCompatActivity {
SurfaceView cameraView;
BarcodeDetector barcode;
CameraSource cameraSource;
SurfaceHolder holder;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_leer_qr);
    cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
    cameraView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
    holder = cameraView.getHolder();
    barcode = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
            .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
            .build();
    if(!barcode.isOperational()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, Couldn't setup the detector", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        this.finish();
    }
    cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcode)
            .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
            .setRequestedFps(24)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(1920,1024)
            .build();
    cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try{
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(LeerQR.this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            cameraSource.stop();

        }
    });
    barcode.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
        @Override
        public void release() {

        }

        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes =  detections.getDetectedItems();
            if(barcodes.size() > 0){
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                //String [] variables = barcodes.split(=);
                intent.putExtra("barcode", barcodes.valueAt(0));
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

lo que deseo es pasar el resultado al primer fragment, para poder procesarlo alli

Comment: Donde esta tu fragment? Y la actividad que leer los qr la llamas desde el fragmento o la actividad?

Comment: El fragment esta en el MainActivity, llamo al fragment desde alli por medio de este código:

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor, new LeerQR()).commit();

Cuando lo hago desde la actividad me funciona sin problema, quiero es llamarlos desde el fragment

Comment: Para entender mejor tu problema, agrega el codigo de tu MainActivity, de tu fragmento y de la actividad que lee el QR.

Comment: Creo que la preunta es clara. Quiero que lo que paso en scanbtn hacerlo desde un fragment, como sustituyo startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE); si no abro una actividad si no un fragment, como recibo la data despues de procesada que la recibo con este parametro    intent.putExtra("barcode", barcodes.valueAt(0));  setResult(RESULT_OK, intent); poderla recibir usando fragment en vez de activity, por que en el fragment no puedo usar el intent

Comment: Insisto en que lo agregues para darte una respuesta exacta.

Comment: Ya fue agregado

Comment: has probado la respuesta de abajo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error esta en el contexto que le estas pasando al `Intent` del fragment `PreScan`. Debes pasarle el contexto de la actividad a la que pertenece el fragmento (la actividad a la que pertenece el fragmento es la que lo lanza), no el contexto del fragmento. El contexto de la actividad en el fragmento lo obtienes con el metodo `getActivity()`.

**PreScan**

```
btnscan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LeerQR.class);
       startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

    }
});
```

Otro error que veo es que estas creando un nuevo `Intent` en el metodo `receiveDetections()`, cuando lo que debes de hacer es obtener el `Intent` que lanzo la actividad para retornarle el resultado. El `Intent` lo obtienes con el metodo `getIntent()`.

**LeerQR**

```
@Override
public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
    final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes =  detections.getDetectedItems();
    if(barcodes.size() > 0){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        //String [] variables = barcodes.split(=);
        intent.putExtra("barcode", barcodes.valueAt(0));
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Puedes encontrar un sencillo ejemplo [aquí](https://gitlab.com/david-minaya/RespuestasStackOverflow)